# How to change size of a map in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
    airportsUS <- subset(airports, iso_country == "US" ) #select only US airports

    map <- borders("usa", colour="black", fill="white", size = .3) #map USA continent

    airportsmap <- ggplot(airportsUS) + map 

 print(airportsmap + geom_point(aes(x=airportsUS$longitude_deg, 
    y=airportsUS$latitude_deg), 
    shape=3, size = .1, color = "red")+
    theme(legend.position = "top")+
    ggtitle("Airports"))
```

The problem is when I print my map with airports, I can't see US continent, only my airports, and map of US so small, and I don't know how to "print" it in the middle of my field and make bigger.
Is that mean that I have too much data?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want, but when you add `scale_x_continuous`and `scale_y_continuous`with limits, you can make the mapped area smaller and "zoom in" to the US.

If you are interested in mapping, I suggest you have a look at tmap (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/tmap.pdf). It can produce point maps too.

```
airports <- read.csv("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/7608400/airports.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
airportsUS <- airports
map <- borders("usa", colour="black", fill="white", size = .3) #map USA continent

airportsmap <- ggplot(airportsUS) + map 

print(airportsmap + geom_point(aes(x=airportsUS$longitude, 
                                   y=airportsUS$latitude), 
                               shape=3, size = .1, color = "red")+
        theme(legend.position = "top")+
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125, -67))+
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 50))+
        ggtitle("Airports"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works PERFECT! Exactly what i want. I was interesting in maps and visualization,  that is why thank you for the link!!!

Comment: you're welcome - see this too: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-nutshell.html it's a nice overview, and tmap really is powerful!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Here's how you can add states' abbreviations to the map.  The data is from the links in the comments.

```
# http://openflights.org/data.html
# https://statetable.com/
# https://inkplant.com/code/state-latitudes-longitudes

library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

cols = c("airport_id", "name", "city", "country", "iata_faa", "icao",
         "latitude", "longitude", "altitude", "timezone", "dst",
         "tz_timezone")
airports <- read.csv("airports.dat.txt", header=F, col.names=cols)
states_data <- read.csv('states.csv')
states_geo <- read.csv('states_geo.csv')

states <- tolower(states_data$name)
abbrs <- tolower(states_data$abbreviation)
states_dict <- list()
for (i in seq_along(states)) {
  state <- states[[i]]
  abbr <- abbrs[[i]]
  states_dict[[state]] <- abbr
}

lookupAbbr <- function(x) {
  ab <- states_dict[[tolower(x)]]
  if (is.null(ab)) {
    return("")
  } else {
    return(ab)    
  }
}

states_geo$State <- as.character(states_geo$State)
states_geo$abbr <- sapply(states_geo$State, function(x) lookupAbbr(x))
states_geo$abbr <- toupper(states_geo$abbr)
states_geo <- subset(states_geo, !abbr %in% c("AK", "HI"))

airportsUS <- subset(airports, country=="United States")
airportsUS <- subset(airportsUS, latitude > 23 & latitude < 48)
airportsUS <- subset(airportsUS, longitude < -30 & longitude > -130)

m <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=map_data("state"), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                                         colour="white", fill="gray")

m + geom_point(data=airportsUS, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude),
                    color="red") +
  theme_bw() + coord_equal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(data=states_geo, aes(label=abbr, x=Longitude, y=Latitude))

ggsave("map.png")
```

[map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vh3p.png)

Comment: Thank you, looks cool!
But I see in your map what i am really need. State borders. 
Right now I'm reading about maps, maybe you know how to include state name on the map? Like NY, CA etc

Comment: And I was looked in your Account, sorry) You're a DATA scientist! That is awesome because I'm studying that right now in Germany=) And this should be my project in December))

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. I was worked with Mario and Katharina codes and put on the map State's borders. And now code look like:

```
airports <- read.csv("airports.csv",header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)


library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
airportsUS <- subset(airports, iso_country == "US")
all_states <- map_data("state")
statecenter<-data.frame(long=tapply(all_states$long,all_states$region,mean),lang=tapply(all_states$lat,all_states$region,mean))

g<- ggplot()
statemap <- g + geom_polygon(data=all_states, 
                             aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),
                             colour="black", fill="white" )
statemap


airports_usa_map <- print(statemap + geom_jitter(aes(x=airportsUS$longitude, y=airportsUS$latitude, 
                                 color=airportsUS$type), 
                             shape=3, size = .1)+
        geom_text(aes(x=statecenter$long,y=statecenter$lang,label=rownames(statecenter)),size=3,vjust=-1)+
        theme(legend.position = "top")+
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125, -67))+
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 50))+
        ggtitle("USA Airports"))
#ggsave("airports_usa_map.png")
```

And we will get:
[all US airports by types, and states name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgWML.jpg)

Comment: you might consider facetting for the different airport types: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html - this will give you a map for each type of airport